# Correct use of Sass parent selector?

Tags: sass

I'm trying to make all links on my page have a custom underline similar to [this](https://codepen.io/lixitrixi/pen/ExXVqzL).

Here's what I have so far of a menu that's going to use this feature:
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/lixitrixi/pen/abWqGYj?editors=1100)

The underline, instead of appearing under each link, appears under the "toolbox" div (the link objects' grandparent).

I've tried just making the first CodePen but with the features SCSS allows you (& and nested rules), but I seem to be missing something and won't even show the underline. I'm guessing it has something to do with my use of the parent selector.

How do I make my current code work correctly? If the issue is with my use of parent selectors in general, what is the correct selector to use in this case?

```
(Stack Overflow is making me put this)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `position: absolute` in `::after` therefore the underline will have absolute position not related to the `<a>`. Just add position relative to `<a>` thus inclosing the absolute `::after` content to it.

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #191919cc;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    a {
        position: relative; // here
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
}
```

codepen link: https://codepen.io/ashwin-chandran/pen/BaZjQLz